# Google Chart Date X-Axis not proportionate to length of time

Tags: google-visualization

I have a simple chart plotting data over time. The data points are taken at random time intervals, and I would like the chart X axis (time) to actually reflect the interval between these dates. Currently the x axis always uses the same spacing between two dates, regardless of the span of time covering the delta.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline

should do what you want. It has support for graphing using dates.